# CPU Time difference between eosflare and EOS Resource Planner

Tags: smart-contract

i would like know why these two sites shwo different CPU Time i have/(could have) with my Account.

Example:

- 1000 EOS on EOS Resource Planner => 45 s/day
- 1000 EOS on eosflare => 14,4 s/day (scaled)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This could have to do with the adjustment for available CPU based on the network's current available CPU/Bandwidth. In other words now that the network is being saturated for various reasons, the available resources per EOS is less because more is being used.

You are guaranteed a minimum amount of CPU/Bandwidth based on holding EOS. EOS also awards more use of the network in times where there is less saturation.